# JavaFX client:run Mysql Connection Error Can't load resource bundle

Tags: mysql, javafx, gluon

it happens when I run the client:run.

what I want is to connect the MySQL database to my project. and give it to the client. so any idea. how to solve it.

Thanks In advance.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:519)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:315)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:49)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:67)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl$Type.getImplementingInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:241)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl$Type.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:211)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:280)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:195)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at org.quiz.service.MySQL.authorize(MySQL.java:11)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at org.quiz.App.start(App.java:34)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:102)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      ... 3 more
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load resource bundle due to underlying exception java.util.MissingResourceException: Resource bundle not found com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages. Register the resource bundle using the option -H:IncludeResourceBundles=com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages.
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:60)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      ... 26 more
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Resource bundle not found com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages. Register the resource bundle using the option -H:IncludeResourceBundles=com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages.
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.LocalizationSupport.getCached(LocalizationSupport.java:66)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:56)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.mysql.cj.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:58)
[Fri Apr 09 15:52:10 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      ... 28 more
```

I guess they say to add this -H:IncludeResourceBundles=com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages. and I don't know where to add it. I'm using maven. javafx project.

Comment: Did you try `mvn client:runagent`? That should create the config files for native-image. Also you can use `<bundlesList/>` in the plugin's configuration (see https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_bundleslist)

Comment: Okay! that fixes the error. Thanks Man